# A messy inequality involving integrals

Tags: probability, integration

Let $\theta$ denote a random variable that is smoothly distributed on $[0, 1]$ with PDF $f$. I am trying to show that
$$ pf(p) + \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_p^1 a(\theta, p) f(\theta) d\theta < 0$$
for all $p \in [0, 1]$, where

$$ a(\theta, p) = \text{ProductLog}\left[\left(\sqrt{2(p-\mathbb{E}[\theta| \theta < p])}-1\right) e^{\sqrt{2(p-\mathbb{E}[\theta| \theta < p])}+p-\theta-1}\right]+\theta+1 $$

Using the Leibniz rule, the desired inequality can be written as
$$ pf(p) +  \int_p^1 f(\theta)\frac{\partial a(\theta, p)}{\partial p} d\theta - a(p, p) < 0$$

However, I can't get further than this. I feel like this should be do-able using Mathematica (even though the expressions seem messy...); does anyone have any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: There are several strange things in the question. What is $W$? If it's a Wiener process, then $a(\theta,p)$ may be close to $-\infty$ with nonzero probability and the inequality will not be true. Moreover, there is a term $\mathbf{E} (\theta |\theta < p)$. So, $\theta$ is a random variable? If so, then how do you understand $\int_p^1 ... d\theta$? And  if $\int_p^1 ... d\theta$ is a usual Lebesgue integral, then $\theta$ is nonrandom and hence the definition of $a(\theta,p)$ is very strange. 
Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @BotnakovN. Apologies not for clarifying; $W$ is the product log function. There is also a typo which I will fix.

Comment: It's useful to write in the question what was meant by "smoothly distributed" because it's not a standard notion.

Comment: My apologies if I wasn't clear; I meant that the CDF $F$ is continuous (so no atoms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true.

**Proof**.
Suppose that the claim is true. There exists $p_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $f(p_0) > 0$.
Consider $\tilde{f}(p)$ such that $\tilde{f}(p) =f(p)$ if $p \ne p_0$ and $\tilde{f}(p) = A$ is $p=p_0$. Hence $\tilde{f}(p)$ is also a density of r.v. $\theta$. We supposed that the claim is true, hence
$$ p\tilde{f}(p) + \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_p^1 a(\theta, p) \tilde{f}(\theta) d\theta < 0$$
for all $p \in [0,1]$. But $\frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_p^1 a(\theta, p) \tilde{f}(\theta) d\theta =\frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_p^1 a(\theta, p) f(\theta) d\theta$ because $ a(\theta, p) \tilde{f}(\theta) =  a(\theta, p) f(\theta)$ for all $p \ne p_0$. Hence
$ p\tilde{f}(p) + \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_p^1 a(\theta, p) f(\theta) d\theta < 0$ for all $p \in [0,1]$. Put $p=p_0$. We have
$$ p_0A +  \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_{p_0}^1 a(\theta, p) f(\theta) d\theta < 0 \quad (*)$$ for all $A$. Put $A$ equal to any value which is bigger then $\Big( -\frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_{p_0}^1 a(\theta, p) f(\theta) d\theta + 1\Big)/p_0$. It follows from (*) that
$$ -\frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_{p_0}^1 a(\theta, p) f(\theta) d\theta + 1 +   \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \int_{p_0}^1 a(\theta, p) f(\theta) d\theta < 0.$$ Thus $1 < 0$. We got a contradiction.

Addition: intuition behind the solution. We may change the value of $f$ in some fixed point $p_0$ and get a function $\tilde{f}$, which is equal to $A$ at point $p_0$. Then $\tilde{f}$ is also a density of $theta$. This transformation doesn't change the integral but change the term before the integral and make this term bigger. Hence the inequality becomes a false inequality for big values of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Can you explain a bit more intuitively the argument? Also, surely you cannot choose any $A$ if you want $\tilde{f}(p)$ to be a valid PDF?

Comment: In case it helps, I should add that the claim is definitely true in the case where the distribution is uniform: I checked this by evaluating the expression in closed form and checking that it is negative.

Comment: @afreelunch If we make a density bigger only in one point then it's still denstity. I made an addition to my answer.

Comment: @afreelunch consider the uniform case. You supposed that $f=1$. Consider $\tilde{f} = 1$ if $x \ne \frac12$ , $\tilde{f} = A$ otherwise. Then the claim is false for big values of $A$. Nevertheless $\tilde{f}$ is a density.

Comment: OK thank you! Can you confirm that you took account of the fact that, when you change $f$, you may change $\mathbb{E}[\theta|\theta < p]$ and thus $a(\theta, p)$?

Comment: @afreelunch Yes. I didn't change the distribution and hence I didn't change that expectation. Maybe the claim may be true in case, when the density is continious or smth.like that, but in general case it's not true.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and sorry for being slow on the uptake! But I think your construction then violates the smoothness of $\theta$ (stated in Q)?

Comment: @afreelunch I thought that "smoothly distributed with pdf $f$" meant that it's absolutely continious distribution with density $f$, because a notion "smoothly distributed" is not used usually and I just assumed what was meant. Now I realized that it was meant smth.like "denstity is continious" or "density has several derivatives", so in this sense my example becomes not working.

Comment: @afreelunch After your addition: my example works, because $\tilde{f}$ is still a density of $\theta$. Hence the problem is already solved. And the claim is not true.